# Communicate between UIAutomation and app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-ui-automation

Is there any way for a UIAutomation script to communicate with the running app and just send it information, trigger a function, or change a variable - directly rather than through the UI?

I ask because I am using just using the script to take screenshots and it would be really handy if I could tell the app to set a couple of integers rather than dealing with somewhat unreliable and difficult to set up multitouch gestures and timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumble upon this today while having same need.
I have solved this is by using GCDWebServer and sending post message from my app to the local web server end point hosted in UIAutomation.